# Random Registration Path

Tags: users

I am developing a site where we'll have standard users and somekind of "VIP" users. VIP user can only register by invitation and should record who have invited by who. Besides, I want to have 2 registration forms for each type of user.

I was trying to use [referral](https://www.drupal.org/project/referral) and [registration_invite module](https://www.drupal.org/project/registration_invite) but last one doesn't work properly. Referral module and seems useful to me since it store information about who refer who to registration form. But I need VIP registration path to be random (or someway unaccessible to users who have not been invited)